# MySQL INNER JOIN COUNT() query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with two tables. One called 'Combatants' with a column 'combatantID'. Another called 'Kills' with columns 'killID', 'shooter' and 'victim'. Both shooter and victim are foreign keys pointing to `Combatants.combatantID'. I would like to make a query that will return data in a table with the form:

combatantID,kills,deaths

I can get it working for either kills or deaths but not both. To do one or the other I've been using this query:

```
SELECT Combatants.combatantID, COUNT(K1.killID) as kills
FROM Combatants 
INNER JOIN Kills as K1 ON K1.shooter=Combatants.combatantID
GROUP BY Combatants.combatantID
```

However if I put another `INNER JOIN with table Kills as K2 and add  COUNT(K2.killID) as deaths` I get an odd result that I think is the sum of all player kills, all player deaths instead of player specific kills, deaths.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: count is `group` related operation... and try left joins for don't change result rows number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different options, you could count `DISTINCT killID`:

```
SELECT
  Combatants.combatantID,
  COUNT(DISTINCT K1.killID) as kills,
  COUNT(DISTINCT k2.killID) as deaths
FROM
  Combatants INNER JOIN Kills as K1 ON K1.shooter=Combatants.combatantID
  INNER JOIN Kills as K2 ON K2.victim=Combatants.combatantID
GROUP BY
  Combatants.combatantID
```

or you can perform your counts in two different subquery:

```
SELECT
  Combatants.combatantID,
  k1.kills,
  k2.deaths
FROM
  Combatants INNER JOIN (
    SELECT shooter, COUNT(*) AS Kills
    FROM kills
    GROUP BY shooter
  ) k1 ON k1.shooter = Combatants.combatantID
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT victim, COUNT(*) AS deaths
    FROM kills
    GROUP BY victim
  ) k2 ON k1.victim = Combatants.combatantID
```

maybe it's better to use a LEFT JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN, in case a combatant has not shot anyone, or has never been a victim.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did go with a LEFT JOIN as you suggested.